# Сравнение значений в двух массивах

Tags: javascript, массивы

Начало стандартное: я новичок в JavaScript.
Задача: 
Функция принимает 2 массива с уникальными элементами
Функция должна возвращать число элементов, которые содержаться в обеих массивах

Пример:

```
fourth(['Erlang', 'JavaScript'], ['Go', 'C++', 'Erlang']); // 1
```

Как это реализовал:

```
function fourth(arr1, arr2) {

  var count = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
      arr1_to_str = arr1[i].toString();
      arr2_to_str = arr2[j].toString();
      if(arr1_to_str == arr2_to_str) {
          count +=1;
          alert('count = ' + count);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
```

Функция работает, если подать на вход следующие аргументы:

```
var arr1 = ['Erlang', 'JavaScript'];
var arr2 = ['Go', 'C++', 'Erlang'];

var arr1 = ['incapsulation','OOP','array'];
var arr2 = ['time', 'propert','paralelism','OOP'];

var arr1 = [ true, 3, 9, 11, 15 ];
var arr2 = [ true, 3, 11 ];
```

И даже с такими (преобразовал оба аргумента в строку):

```
var arr1 = [1];
var arr2 = [true];
```

А вот если на вход подать:

```
var arr1 = [1];
var arr2 = ["1"];
```

функция возвращает 1, а должно 0, так как 1 не давно "1".

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.
Благодарю.

Comment: Уберите `toString` и сравнивайте с помощью `===`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ. Помогло.

Comment: Вот и славненько, не за что :)

Comment: А если в массиве будут объекты, то какие объекты будут считаться равными? Например `var arr1 = [{x:1}];
var arr2 = [{x:1}];`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, объекты - ссылочные типы. Так что равными будут считаться объекты с одинаковыми ссылками (то есть объект равен только самому себе). То есть при `let foo = { baz: "baz" }; let bar = { ...foo };` получаем, что `foo == foo`, но `foo != bar`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov спасибо, я знаю, как сравниваются объекты в js. Интересно требование в задачи у ТС.

Answer (score 2):

как-нибудь так еще можно, например.

```js
function fourth(a,b){
    return a.reduce((acc,av) => acc + b.some(bv => av === bv), 0);
}

var res = fourth(['Erlang', 'JavaScript',1], ['Go', 'C++', 'Erlang',1]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

В данном случае, Вам необходимо проверять тип данных, так как Вы переводите всё в строчный вариант. 
Либо не делайте этого и сравнивайте точным сравнением через `===`, либо проверяйте тип данных.
В данном случае, мы проверяем тип данных каждого элемента массива(`bz` и `bz1` и сравниваем их).
Вот пример:

```js
    function fourth(arr1, arr2) {

        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            var bz = typeof(arr1[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                var bz1 = typeof(arr2[j]);
                arr1_to_str = arr1[i].toString();
                arr2_to_str = arr2[j].toString();
                if (arr1_to_str == arr2_to_str && bz == bz1) {
                    count += 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    console.log(fourth(['Erlang', 'JavaScript'],['Go', 'C++', 'Erlang']));

    console.log(fourth(['incapsulation','OOP','array'],['time', 'propert','paralelism','OOP']));

    console.log(fourth([ true, 3, 9, 11, 15 ],[ true, 3, 11 ]));
    console.log(fourth([1],[true]));
    console.log(fourth([1],["1"]));
```

Comment: @Denis640Kb, может, дело как раз было в том, что Вы оставили сомнительное решение в лице сравнения строковой репрезентации значений, после чего впилили туда ручную проверку типа? И это вместо того, чтобы использовать оператор `===`, который и включает в себя проверку типов заодно.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Изначально автор вопроса использовал перевод в строку, о чём было сразу же написано, если Вы не обратили внимание. Изменение кода втора не приветствуется. Ответ дан и он корректен.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, кто Вам сказал такую глупость, что код ТС менять нельзя? И если так, то зачем же Вы сами его поменяли, вставив туда проверку типов?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, заметьте, я Вас не оскорблял, а наоборот, обратив внимание на Вашу просьбу, объяснил Вам, за что Вашему ответу ставят минусы. В ответ Вы прикрылись несуществующими правилами (так и не предоставив доказательств их существования. Потому что их нет) и буквально набросились на меня, опустившись в итоге до прямых оскорблений.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, аргументы-с в наличии: минусы ставят из-за того, что код плох; код плох по той причине, что там вместо `a === b` используется `a.toString() == b.toString() && typeof(a) == typeof(b)`. Вы же в ответ только оперировали к правилу, которого нет (я знаю свод правил крайне хорошо, я здесь уже много лет), то есть Ваш "аргумент" за собой попросту ничего не имеет.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, в общем, буду ждать ссылочки на "правило", чтобы не вести дальше эту полемику. Если Вы таковое найдёте, то я перед Вами извинюсь и заменю свой downvote на upvote

Comment: Коллеги, прошу не ссорится.

В самом начале вопроса мной специально был сделан акцент на то, что я новичок в программировании на JavaScript. Программирование я изучал тогда, когда немалого количества пользователей данного ресурса еще и в помине не было (возможно еще и их родители не вошли в репродуктивный возраст) - в 1994 году в военному училище. И учили нас Pascal’ю на ЕС СВМ. Опыт программирования очень не большой: год на Delphi + InterBase (1999-2000) и год на PL/SQL в Oracle Report/Form Builder (2002-2003). Потом перерыв до сегодняшнего года. Прошу отнестись к этому с пониманием.

Comment: Сейчас я заново учусь и мой код не прост плох, он ужасен. И мне это известно.
Уверен, что с помощью курсов, книг, форумов, комментариев и практики смогу начать писать рабочий и красивый код. Если повезет, найду хорошего, умного и терпеливого наставника.

Благодарю за ответ @Kir_Antipov. Он мне помог. Буду разбираться в чем разница между «==» и «===».

Comment: Что же качается a.toString() == b.toString(), то по причине малых знаний и была использована данная конструкция, так как я понимаю, что в программировании сравнивая 1 и true будет сравниваться 1 и 1, а не «1» и «true». Таким образом было сделано преобразование к тому типу данных, сравнение которых ожидалось при постановке задачи.

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев, прошу извинить за эту тираду под Вашим вопросом :) Именно по причине того, что тему может начать новичок (в текущей сфере) у нас и нет правила, что в ответ нужно бездумно копировать код из вопроса лишь за малыми исправлениями.

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев, Pascal, Delphi - славные были времена хД Не в военном, конечно, училище, но тоже с них начинал когда-то. Коли учите JS, советую частично абстрагироваться от старых знаний, ибо язык сей весьма и весьма своеобразен. Что касается разницы `==` и `===`, она крайне проста: `1 == "1"`, но `1 !== "1"`. То есть `==` сначала попытается привести операнды к одному типу, после чего уже выполнит сравнение, а вот `===` (и `!==`) таким не занимается и проверяет на равенство значения только одного и того же типа

Comment: Благодарю Вас за разъяснение. Коротко и, самое главное, понятно.

Что касается «… советую частично абстрагироваться от старых знаний ..», полностью с Вами соглашусь.
За 20 лет многое изменилось в программировании. Одно только ООП чего стоит. 
В военном училище нам об этом не рассказывали. 
Прочел книгу «Объектно-ориентированное мышление» Вайсфельда. Сейчас читаю Мартина «Идеальный программист. Как стать профессионалом разработки ПО».
И курсы. Благо сейчас их много.

Comment: @АлександрНиколаев, это правильно :) Но JS все же не обладает ООП в чистом виде, оно там существует только в качестве синтаксической обёртки над системой прототипов. Вы вообще какие языки решили изучать?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Python. Очень мне его синтаксис понравился. Основная цель - работать с данными. Так уж получилось много лет назад, что работать с базами данных мне очень понравилось. Надоело, когда в служил по контракту в батальоне, одни и те же ФИО/звания в WORD/EXCEL копипастить.

Comment: Была система, написанная на Paradox, доставшаяся от предыдущего коллеги лейтинанта-двухгодичника (ПОЛИТЕХ). Она не маштабировалась. Жить могла на одном компьютере. Все это не устраивало. Так как Delphi и Paradox - детища одной компании, выбор среды разработки и СУБД был очевиден для меня.

Python мне чем-то напоминает Pascal. 

Что же касается приведенных здесь примеров на JS, то это тестовое задание от одной школы. Видимо проверяют уровень подготовки поступающих. Решил себя проверить.